# Laravel Save multiple table rows to the database

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to save multiple table rows to the database. And when I try run my code, nothing saves to the database. Here's my code for the blade template:

```
<form action="{{ action('BorrowBookController@store') }}" method="POST">
    @csrf
    <div class="form-group">
        <select class="form-control" name="student[]">
            @foreach( $students as $row )
            <option value="{{ $row->id }}">{{ $row->FirstName }} {{ $row->LastName }}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>

    <h2>List of Books Borrowed</h2>
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table id="books-detail-table" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width: 100%;">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Title</th>
                    <th>Quantity</th>
                    <th>
                        <button id="addBtn" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-success">
                            <span data-feather="plus"></span>
                        </button>
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="tbody">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <select class="form-control" name="book[]">
                                @foreach( $books as $row )
                                <option value="{{ $row->id }}">{{ $row->title}}</option>
                                @endforeach
                            </select>

                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="number" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="quantity[]" placeholder="Qty" required>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>

    </div>
    <div class="btn-toolbar mb-2 mb-md-0">
        <div class="btn-group mr-2">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">
                <span data-feather="save"></span>
                Submit
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

And here's my controller for reference:
`BorrowBookController@store`

```
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $timeToday = Carbon::now();
        $this->validate($request, [
            'student_id'   => 'required',
            'book_id'      => 'required',
            'quantity'     => 'required',
        ]);

        $student_id    = $request->input('student[]');
        $book_id       = $request->input('book[]');
        $quantity      = $request->input('quantity[]');
        $date_borrowed = $timeToday->toDateTimeString();
        $return_date   = 0;
        $status        = "ACTIVE";

        for ($i = 0; $i < count($student_id); $i++) {
            $data = [
                'student_id' => $student_id[$i],
                'book_id' => $book_id[$i],
                'quantity' => $quantity[$i],
                'date_borrowed' => $date_borrowed[$i],
                'return_date' => $return_date[$i],
                'status' => $status,
            ];
            BorrowBook::create($data);
        }

        return redirect('/borrow_books')->with('success', 'Successfully borrowed a book.');
    }
```

I don't really know where my problem is. It's either on the controller or the blade template. How can I achieve in solving this kind of issue? I hope everyone can help me with this. Thank you.

Comment: Your selects are not multiple, so I guess your `$student_id` is not an array, so the count will be 0, and your loop will not be triggered. Dump your variables, and look at your networks to see and understand your request.

Comment: Just try `$request->student` if your input is array it will return array.

Comment: when you pass an input named `xxx[]` you don't need to include `[]` in PHP since PHP removes that an interprets the input as an array automatically. You just need `$request->input('student')`.  I'm not sure why you're creating input arrays though, you will only ever have 1 value in them based on the code you shared.

Comment: Also in general when facing such bugs, find out the most likely problem and try to dd(); and print the values. dd($student_id); would probably tell you why that loop is not running :)

Comment: @mrhn where can i usally place the `dd()`?

Comment: anywhere, it means dump and die, so it prints its contents and kills the process

Answer (score 1):

check the model class BorrowBook and set the fillable property
without the column name inside fillable you can not add data through create method

```php
<?php

class BorrowBook extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
                'student_id' ,
                'book_id',
                'quantity' ,
                'date_borrowed' ,
                'return_date' ,
                'status'];
}
```